# How to get the activated tab?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

With bootstrap 5, I was never able to get the activated tab. according to their [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/) I just get the ID of the first button, not the activated tab and nothing else.

```js
var tabEl = document.querySelector('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')
tabEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  alert(event.target.id) // newly activated tab
  // event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

I need tabs ID once its related button is clicked.

Comment: The active nav-item gets the class "active". You can select that using CSS and/or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is only finding the first `button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]` you need to use  `document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')` then loop through the NodeList.

### Edit

Selecting the actual active tab-pane element takes a little more legwork. The `event.target` and `event.relatedTarget` are the tab buttons and their `data-bs-target` attribute value is the selector for the associated tab-pane.
Checkout the updated snippet:

```js
var tabEl = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')
//console.log(tabEl)
for (i = 0; i < tabEl.length; i++) {
  tabEl[i].addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
    const activated_pane = document.querySelector(event.target.getAttribute('data-bs-target'))
    const deactivated_pane = document.querySelector(event.relatedTarget.getAttribute('data-bs-target'))

    console.log(activated_pane.id)
    // console.log(deactivated_pane.id)

    // do stuff
    activated_pane.append(' hello ' + activated_pane.id)

  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/o4yxLshq/)

Comment: The active nav-item gets the class "active". You can select that using CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, yes however, if you have more than one set of tabs this method insures you are getting the correct pane for which the clicked button was configured to control. I'm using the the same data that bootstrap.js is using to target the element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using querySelector, which selects only first element. Use querySelectorAll, which selects all the tabs.

```js
/*
// Using Vanilla JS
var tabEl = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')
tabEl.forEach(function(el){
el.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  alert(event.target.id) // newly activated tab
  // event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
})

*/

/*
// Using jQuery

*/

$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {     // here is the new selected tab id     
var selectedTabId = e.target.id;   
console.log('tab changed', selectedTabId); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The active nav-item gets the class "active". You can select that using CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @Alaksandar, your solution with palin JS is working in my code. Though same approach with JQuery its not working. here is my code `$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // here is the new selected tab id
    var selectedTabId = e.target.id;
  console.log('tab changed');
});` can you please check this.

Comment: shown.bs.tab is the bootstrap customEvent not javascript event. you need to bind click event on the button. The code is updated for your reference.